# is there a way to download the frozen graph ( .pb file ) of PoseNet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I intend to use posenet in python and not in browser, for that I need the model as a frozen graph to do inference on. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ported Google's tfjs PoseNet to Python over the holidays. The demo apps in the repository automatically download the weights, freeze a graph, and save to a model file. You can grab this model and use in any TF variant.

I wrote a Python version of the multi-person post processing code that uses  vectorized scipy/numpy ops to speed a few parts. I have not done exhaustive testing of this part, but with a number of spot checks on various test images against the reference, and using it for some other sources, it seems to be reasonably close to the original, and faster :)

Python + TF at https://github.com/rwightman/posenet-python

I also did a PyTorch conversion at https://github.com/rwightman/posenet-pytorch

And if you happen to be looking for a CoreML port at some point, I started off with the weight conversion code from this project https://github.com/infocom-tpo/PoseNet-CoreML

Answer (score 1):

We currently do not have the frozen graph for inference publicly, however you could download the assets and run them in a Node.js environment.